# Output of cv.glm vs. cv.glmnet

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm trying to do cross validation for a dataset that I want to fit a Poisson model to. I notice, however, that I get very different outputs from the functions `cv.glm` and `cv.glmnet` when I use `lambda = 0`. Below is my code for the basic Poisson model (the first part is setup of the data set):

```
game_soon <- function(game_type, hour){
  ret_vec <- c()
  len_game_type <- length(game_type)
  for(i in 1:len_game_type){
    if(game_type[i] == 'N' && hour[i] >= 16){
      ret_vec <- c(ret_vec, 1)
    }
    else if(game_type[i] == 'D' && hour[i] >= 10 && hour[i] <= 17){
      ret_vec <- c(ret_vec, 1)
    }
    else{
      ret_vec <- c(ret_vec, 0)
    }
  }
  return(ret_vec)
}

wrigley_agg <- read.csv("/Users/eweine/Desktop/myDivvy/export/EWEINE/WR/WRIGLEY_DIVVY/data", header=FALSE)

colnames(wrigley_agg) <- c("Checkouts", "Temp", "Humidity", "Rain_Intensity", 
                           "Rain_Total", "Hour", "DOY", "Weekday", "Cubs_Game")
game_vec <- wrigley_agg$Cubs_Game
hour_vec <- wrigley_agg$Hour
new_column <- game_soon(game_vec, hour_vec)
wrigley_agg$Game_Soon <- new_column

require(glm)
require(boot)


basic_poisson <- glm(Checkouts ~ Weekday + Game_Soon + poly(Hour, 6) + 
poly(Temp, 4) + poly(Rain_Intensity, 4), data=wrigley_agg, family=poisson)

cv_possion <- cv.glm(wrigley_agg, basic_poisson, K=10)

print(cv_possion)
```

My output is:

```
[1] 958.9232 958.5509
```

Below is my code for the `cv.glmnet` model:

```
x_pois <- model.matrix(Checkouts ~ Weekday + Game_Soon + poly(Hour, 6) + poly(Temp, 4) + 
                                   poly(Rain_Intensity, 4), data=wrigley_agg)
y_pois <- wrigley_agg$Checkouts

cv_lasso_pois <- cv.glmnet(x_pois, y_pois, family="poisson", alpha=1, lambda=seq(1, 0, -1))
no_penalty_cv <- cv_lasso_pois$cvm[cv_lasso_pois$lambda == 0]
print(no_penalty_cv)
```

And my output is:

```
[1] 13.41691
```

The data can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/data_7).

Why are these values so different?

Comment: > cv.glm ... #
Error: object 'cv.glm' not found

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: You didn't include a library call to load a package that might contain all the functions and data ... although my guess is that the dataset might not be there, either. Do read [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks, I've updated all of the information

Comment: No, you haven't. `In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/eweine/Desktop/myDivvy/export/EWEINE/WR/WRIGLEY_DIVVY/data': No such file or directory`  And what actually happened at your console when you executed `require(glm)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. 
The difference between the mean cross-validated errors given by `cv.glm` and `cv.glmnet` (with `lambda=0`) is due to the different cost functions used by the two commands.
For poisson models, `cv.glm` uses by default the **average squared error** while `cv.glmnet` uses **deviance**.
Below I define a function `devi` that calculates deviance as required by `cv.glm`:

```
library(glmnet)
library(boot)

basic_poisson <- glm(Checkouts ~ Weekday + Game_Soon + poly(Hour, 6) + 
poly(Temp, 4) + poly(Rain_Intensity, 4), data = wrigley_agg, family = 
poisson)

devi <- function(y, eta) {
        deveta = y * log(eta) - eta
        devy = y * log(y) - y
        devy[y == 0] = 0
        mean(2 * (devy - deveta))
} 

set.seed(1)
cv_poisson <- cv.glm(data=wrigley_agg, glmfit=basic_poisson, cost=devi, K = 10)
print(cv_poisson$delta)
```

The estimated (raw and adjusted) mean cross-validated errors now are:

```
[1] 13.42184 13.41605
```

They are very close to the error given by `cv.glmnet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In general, is there a package that can consistently calculate cv for models of many different types? This would make cross validation much easier.

Comment: @EricWeine The `cv.glmnet` function can consistently calculate cv errors for many different models. I suggest to use this command for penalized and unpenalized models.